# Using open-ended params in TS with classes

Tags: typescript

In the following example, I'm expecting the length of the array passed to the method `test` to match.
Can anyone explain why it doesn't work as expected?

```
class Beef
{
    public id: number;
}

class Steak
{
    public run()
    {
        const testBeefs = this.getBeef();
        console.log('Should be 5, got '+ testBeefs.length);
        
        const result = this.test(testBeefs);

        return result;
    }
    
    private getBeef():Beef[]
    {
        const output: Beef[] = [];
        for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            const newBeef = new Beef();
            newBeef.id = i;
            output.push(newBeef);
        }
        return output;
    }

    private test(...beefs: Beef[]): number
    {
        console.log('Should be 5, got '+ beefs.length);
        
        var output = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < beefs.length; i++)
            output += beefs[i].id;
          
        return output;
    }
}
```

According to the compiler it seems that `test` is expecting and instance of `Beef`, not `Beef[]`. Is there a simpler way?

Example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDDGBsEMGdoAgEIFMkDNgG9hx3ADgK4BG4AlqHKQCYBccAdgQLZFIBOA3MAL4gQzwAygBckkANaZsuQiXJw2BegAoAlNJxZc2uKAD29aMLiijyNPAC8JgBaloAOgDmSYedRquO3PsN7wSA7gek7KAOSCNnoE4FRwrHAArAA0cE56xmEA1CZIZiiojgH0TsI2ql7ecBo6vkYKeTHG1mX2DqbCyh3u0BUgVQ3CBGz0DdBNlTi82jV4bKQAbpCiaa7uajTuANoAujVaVXXG0cKEwnTbO3DWu5M6qHpscMpLT6TXcACMHJRwADzWRI-UhZLLqAYHAY4I4MJAAd3cH3o8MQBU8NQGyIRBQc1A+pDuAxOZwchGgNmUWPcfQG0yqbFcw1GxIIwjuvFm8yWKw6ygc-NYFguBV2qjojBY7H2GJ8Bmg-kCwVCESiMTiCRSaQycGy8QKRSQJTKNKqMpwrzgLOacAADITcA8ni9IG8Pnbfn89RYgobSjZgaDwVUAJBWuBZayCwpbUg7XFUe0zAYMoYjS2ss7snh8OXGIxicRIlEiAvosByhVBELKfMSByKFSqCpAA)

To explain my code, calling run will:

1. Create an array via `getBeef` with 5 instances of the class `Beef` called `testBeefs`
2. Pass `testBeefs` to the method `test`
3. `test` will sum the `id` field of each `Beef` instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test` is not expecting an array, it is expecting an unspecified number of arguments of the type `Beef`.

Either call it like:

```
const result = this.test(...testBeefs)
```

Or change the signature to simply use an array for the first argument:

```
private test(beefs: Beef[]): number
```